# What are the official social media accounts associated with IOTA?

Tags: untagged

When I search for the currency tag [$iota](https://twitter.com/search?q=%24IOTA&src=ctag) on Twitter I'm presented with an couple of accounts which I don't believe to be officially associated with IOTA.

Assuming IOTA does have an official presence on social networks: what are the official social media accounts associated with IOTA?

Comment: I appreciate that this question may be deemed off-topic. For newcomers to the Stack Exchange network, please use the Close button below my post if you do believe this to be off-topic.

Comment: Tricky to keep up to date. Furthermore, the question doesn't specify whose official account you're looking for. (Even though the assumption of the IOTA foundation lies near.) Most importantly however looking  going anywhere but to the source to evaluate the *official something* of anyone is just bad practice. Thus, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [Twitter](https://twitter.com/iotatoken)

The official [Blog](https://blog.iota.org/)

The official [Website](https://iota.org/)

The official [Newsletter](https://powered.by.rabbut.com/p/QA8R)

The official [Forum](https://forum.iota.org/)

The official [Slack](http://slack.iota.org/)

You can also find them on the reddit page on the right side!

Comment: All those are literally one click from the official site. There's no use in duplicating this on Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/ 
is also very nice

Comment: That Slack link doesn't work: "This invite link is no longer active."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help to figure out what is the position of the Foundation regarding HelloIOTA forum.[image]

Comment: You should probably just add this as an edit to your [original answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/349/38) to clarify it and remove this. This isn't really an answer itself, rather it complements your other post.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the forum, at the present, the one that is being updated by the community and aim to be the main source of information and support in the future is https://forum.helloiota.com/ as you can see on this post on twitter https://twitter.com/IOTASupport

Comment: There is literally not once the word official in there ;)

Comment: seems totally not linked, nor supported by the iota foundation in any way